# Condition for Integrability of an Almost Complex Structure

Tags: complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds, general-relativity

The following question concerns a remark made in the paper:

> Lebrun, C., *Complete Ricci-flat Kähler metrics on $\mathbb{C}^n$ need not be flat*, Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics, Volume **52** (1991), Part 2.

Specifically, we want to show that the Taub-NUT metric on $\mathbb{S}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^+$ is a Ricci-flat Kähler metric using the Gibbons-Hawking ansatz.

Let $V : = 1 + 1/(2r) : \mathbb{R}^3 - \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}^+$, and let $\pi : M_0 \to \mathbb{R}^3 - \{ 0 \}$ denote the $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle of Chern class $-1$, which we equip with the connection of curvature $\textbf{F} = \ast dV$. Let $\omega$ denote the connection form of this connection, and let $ds^2$ denote the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $$g = V \pi^{\ast} ds^2 + V^{-1} \omega^2,$$ gives a metric on $M_0$ called the *Taub-NUT* metric.

Let now $\partial/\partial x$ be a unit vector on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and take some local trivialisation of $\pi : M_0 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with vertical coordinate $t$, so that $\omega = dt + \vartheta$ for some $1$-form $\vartheta$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying $d \vartheta = \ast dV$ which represents the connection in this gauge.

Then our complex structure $J$ is given on $1$-forms by $$dx \mapsto V^{-1}(dt + \vartheta), \hspace{0.5cm} dy \mapsto dz,$$ which is indeed integrable because \begin{eqnarray*}
d[V dx + i(dt + \vartheta)] &=& [(-V_y + i V_z) dx - i V_x dz] \wedge (dy + i dz),
\end{eqnarray*}

showing that the differential ideal generated by $dy + i dz$ and $V dx + i(dt + i\vartheta)$ is closed.

> **Q:** Does someone have a reference for this definition of integrability?